# c++ custom type vector optimization

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, temporary, custom-type

I have an A class and it has a private int _i member. I want n number of A instances to be stored in a vector. Thus, i gave an initial capacity to the vector. Also, i want to hold objects with different _i values, and construct objects with different values in a loop. Corresponding code is as follows:

```
 #include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A( int i = -1 ) { _i = i; cout << "cc  " << _i << endl; }
    A( const A &other ) { _i = other._i; cout << "ccc " << _i << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "dc  " << _i << endl; }
    int get_i() const { return _i; }
private:
    int _i;
};

const int n = 2;

vector<A> v( n );

int main()
{
    cout << "---" << endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        v[i] = A( i );

    cout << "---" << endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        cout << v[i].get_i() << endl;

    cin.ignore( 1 );

    return 0;
}

output:

cc  -1
ccc -1
dc  -1
cc  -1
ccc -1
dc  -1
---
cc  0
dc  0
cc  1
dc  1
---
0
1
```

I think, initial capacity parameter, creates and destructs objects unnecessarily at first. And in the first loop temporary objects are also created unnecessarily. My question is how i can fix the code to directly pass objects into vector without default and temporary object construction? Below is the my desired output:

```
---
cc  0
cc  1
---
0
1
```

Accutually, i don't know whether deafult and temporary object creation expose a performance problem or not.

Comment: That code doesn't generate that output.

Comment: Accutually, i think it varies by compiler. @BenVoigt

Comment: No, I mean *that* code won't print out `-1` on any compiler.

Comment: why not?, i posted real outputs

Comment: sorry, you 're right. I edited the question done wrong post previosuly.

Answer (score 3):

Use `reserve`, not `resize`, to set capacity.  And then use `emplace_back` for in-place construction to avoid temporaries.

```
vector<A> v;

int main()
{
    v.reserve(n)
    cout << "---" << endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        v.emplace_back( 1 );
}
```

Comment: cc  0
ccc 0
dc  0
cc  1
ccc 1
dc  1

Comment: Above is the output for now. Can this be made without copy constructor call?

Comment: @Ian: [I don't see a copy constructor call](http://ideone.com/rUuOJN).  Are you sure you used `emplace_back(i)` as I recommended, and not `push_back(A(i))` or `emplace_back(A(i))`?